# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.camera')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Im trying to show the camera feed from the selfie camera inside of a `<View>` component, and I've been getting this error constantly. I've tried reinstalling react-native-camera and using expo-camera
, but im all out of ideas.
Code:

```
import {RNCamera, Camera} from 'react-native-camera'
import { View,Text,Screen,Image  } from 'react-native';
import Button from 'apsl-react-native-button';
import React from 'react';

export default function Reunion ({navigation}){
    return (
        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            flex:1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}>
        <View
        style={{
            position: 'relative',
            left:0,
            top:-15,
            width:1080,
            height:480,
            backgroundColor: '#c4c4c4'
        }}
        >
        <RNCamera
          style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}
          captureAudio={false}
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = this.camera.bind(this )
            this.camera = ref
          }}
        />
            
        </View>


        </View>
    )
}
```

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He7vZ.png)

Comment: don't use "this" in "Functional  Components", use "useRef" or "createRef"

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
import {RNCamera, Camera} from 'react-native-camera'
import { View,Text,Screen,Image  } from 'react-native';
import Button from 'apsl-react-native-button';
import React from 'react';

export default function Reunion ({navigation}){

    const cameraRef = React.createRef();

    return (
        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            flex:1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}>
        <View
        style={{
            position: 'relative',
            left:0,
            top:-15,
            width:1080,
            height:480,
            backgroundColor: '#c4c4c4'
        }}
        >
        <RNCamera
          style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}
          captureAudio={false}
          ref={cameraRef}
        />
            
        </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```